# Python - calling function and continuing main program

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I am collecting data at a set frequency (e.g. 8hz) this data is modified, stored, and then occasionally sent out to be written.

I am running into a timing issue due to streaming/writing the data. When the program writes the data (every 5 seconds) it takes longer than 1/8hz (0.125s) to do so. This creates a delay in my timing for data acquisition.

What I want to do is to call my write function and have it run but also allow my main program to keep running so that there is no delay in timing.

I have tried to use a few different methods but with little luck: threading, multiprocessing, and asyncio. It is very possible I am using them incorrectly though.

An very simplified version of what I am doing:

```py
    def main():
        while True:
            curTime = datetime.datetime.now()
            while curTime < nextTime:
                continue
            data = collectData() #collect data (serial port, tcp, etc.)
            pdata = processData(data) #process data
            hdata = holdData(hdata) #store data stream for occasional writing

            if len(hdata) > 8*5:
                writeData(hdata) #send data to be written - takes too long and causes delay in next sample > 0.125s from previous.


            nextTime = curTime + datetime.timedelta(microsecond = 125000) #adjust next time for measurement - 0.125s after last time data was collected.
```

In the above code. I want to call writeData and have that function do it's thing, but keep my main function moving along and collect more data. writeData can take as long as it wants, assuming it's faster than my write interval; which it presently is.

I am using python3.

Hopefully this is enough info for some guidance.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You should add threads, subprocesses, forks or asnyc another asynchronous programming methods to program, to execute parts of code simultaneously. There you can find easy way to do it: https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/ `And you should do it divided for more function. Atleast give it while true inside another function :)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track trying to solve your problem by using asynchronous programming. The async programming in Python is tricky by itself as there are principal differences in concurrency implemented using threads (`threading`), processes (`multiprocessing`), or coroutines (`asyncio`). There is no "right" approach, you choose the method which fits best to the current use case.

Your problem has both IO-bound (data fetching and writing) and CPU-bound (data processing) tasks which could be run independently in parallel. Here is how you can do it. Perhaps it's not the most elegant solution, but it will show you the idea of how you can approach such problems.

In our solution, we will use threads for IO-bound tasks and processes for CPU-bound ones. Personally, I'd prefer to use threads for all of the tasks, but in that case, we won't be able to unleash all the power of modern multi-core CPUs to parallelize the data processing because of [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

First, let's import the required modules in our executable script:

```
import time
import random
import signal
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
from queue import Queue, Empty
```

The problem we solve is a [producer-consumer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) problem. The main thread fetches the data at fixed time intervals and puts it into a queue. The processor thread gets data from the queue and submits it to a pool of workers for processing, then collects results and put them into another queue. This queue is constantly read by the writer thread which finally saves the data. Now, we add some constants - a number of worker processes to run in parallel and a data fetch interval in seconds:

```
WORKERS = 4
FETCH_INTERVAL = 1
```

Below is the main thread which is responsible for fetching data every `FETCH_INTERVAL` secs in an infinite loop:

```
def main():
    raw_data = Queue()
    processor = Thread(target=process, args=(raw_data,))
    processor.start()
    i = 0

    try:

        while True:
            t_fetch = time.time()

            # Simulate the data fetching:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            data = i, random.random()
            print("[main] Fetched raw data:", data)

            raw_data.put(data)
            t_elapsed = time.time() - t_fetch

            if t_elapsed < FETCH_INTERVAL:
                time.sleep(FETCH_INTERVAL - t_elapsed)
            else:
                print("[error] The fetch interval is too short!")

            i = i + 1

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("shutting down...")
    finally:
        raw_data.put(None)
        processor.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

We start by defining a `raw_data` queue which will store the fetched data and by starting a `processor` thread which runs a `process` function which takes `raw_data` queue as its argument. Note that we don't just sleep `FETCH_INTERVAL` secs after every data fetch, but we take into account delays caused by data fetching as it's also an IO-bound task. The script runs indefinitely until `Ctrl-C` is pressed. Once interrupted, we put `None` into the queue to signal threads that the processing is over and wait for the `processor` thread to finish. Now, we add a definition of the `process` function which is run by the `processor` thread:

```
def process(raw_data):
    proc_data = Queue()
    writer = Thread(target=write, args=(proc_data,))
    writer.start()

    with Pool(WORKERS, init_worker) as pool:

        while True:
            data_batch = dequeue_data(raw_data, batch_size=WORKERS)

            if not data_batch:
                time.sleep(0.5)
                continue

            results = pool.map(process_data, data_batch)
            print("[processor] Processed raw data:", results)

            for r in results:
                proc_data.put(r)

            if None in data_batch:
                break

    print("joining the writer thread...")
    writer.join()
```

Here, we create a `proc_data` queue which will hold the data processing results for a `writer` thread. The `writer` thread runs a `write` function which we'll define later. Once the `writer` thread is started, we create a `pool` of `WORKERS` processes. Here we use `init_worker` function as `Pool` process initializer in order to ignore keyboard interrupts in worker processes as they are handled in the main thread:

```
def init_worker():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
```

Once the process pool is created, we enter into an infinite loop constantly dequeuing data batches from the `raw_data` queue by calling the `dequeue_data` function which we'll define below. The data batches then get submitted to the worker pool for processing. The `process_data` function will be defined below. Then, we collect the results and put them into the `proc_data` queue which is read by the `writer` thread. In the case there is `None` in the data batch, the processing is interrupted and we wait for the `writer` thread to finish. The `dequeue_data` function is defined as follows:

```
def dequeue_data(data_queue, batch_size):
    items = []

    for _ in range(batch_size):
        try:
            item = data_queue.get(block=False)
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, Empty):
            break

        items.append(item)

    return items
```

Here you see it just tries to fetch and return at most `batch_size` data points from the `data_queue`. If there is no data, it returns an empty list. The `process_data` function does nothing but sleeps 1-5 secs:

```
def process_data(data):

    if data is None:
        return

    # Simulate the data processing:
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))

    return data
```

Finally, we define the `write` function which is running in the `writer` thread:

```
def write(proc_data):

    while True:
        data = proc_data.get()

        if data is None:
            break

        # Simulate the data writing:
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 2))
        print("[writer] Wrote processed data:", data)
```

The infinite loop stops once it gets `None` from the `proc_data` queue. Now, we save all the provided code in a single script, then run and check its outputs:

```
[main] Fetched raw data: (0, 0.8092310624924178)
[main] Fetched raw data: (1, 0.8594148294409398)
[main] Fetched raw data: (2, 0.9059856675215566)
[main] Fetched raw data: (3, 0.5653361157057876)
[main] Fetched raw data: (4, 0.8966396309003691)
[main] Fetched raw data: (5, 0.5772344067614918)
[processor] Processed raw data: [(0, 0.8092310624924178)]
[main] Fetched raw data: (6, 0.4614411399877961)
^Cshutting down...
[writer] Wrote processed data: (0, 0.8092310624924178)
[processor] Processed raw data: [(1, 0.8594148294409398), (2, 0.9059856675215566), (3, 0.5653361157057876), (4, 0.8966396309003691)]
[writer] Wrote processed data: (1, 0.8594148294409398)
[writer] Wrote processed data: (2, 0.9059856675215566)
[processor] Processed raw data: [(5, 0.5772344067614918), (6, 0.4614411399877961), None]
joining the writer thread...
[writer] Wrote processed data: (3, 0.5653361157057876)
[writer] Wrote processed data: (4, 0.8966396309003691)
[writer] Wrote processed data: (5, 0.5772344067614918)
[writer] Wrote processed data: (6, 0.4614411399877961)
```

The `main` thread fetches data at fixed time intervals, while the `processor` processes the data in batches in parallel, and the `writer` saves the results. Once we hit `Ctrl-C` the `main` thread stopped fetching data, then the `processor` thread finished processing the rest of the fetched data and started waiting for the `writer` thread to finish writing the data to disk.

Comment: Thank you constt. I was able to get it working following a similar layout as what you wrote above. I focussed on using the multiprocessing tools only (Process and Queue) where I made a worker to read in data from the queue if present. This works well. I've marked your solution as the accepted as it is very detailed and similar to what ended up working for me. I appreciate the help!